# Dropbox is no longer linking - sign up sheet keeps appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I just opened a project that I hadn't used since updating to Xcode 5.1. It was all working fine previously. Now, whenever I attempt to link to Dropbox, it never passes this line

```
    if([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url])
```

in **AppDelegate** `handleOpenUrl:`. So when the Dropbox sign up sheet appears, I can enter my username and password, then the sheet is dismissed, but **nothing happens and it is not linked**.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you call [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];?

Comment: and setup url scheme with db-YOURKEY?

Comment: Do you have the Dropbox app installed? If so, be sure it's the latest version. There was a bug in a version earlier this year that didn't return you back to the launching app.

Comment: Yes - calling [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession]; in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: and have the url scheme set up. It was all working fine a month ago when I last ran this app. It is the same in the simulator and device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to update to using

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url  sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
```

I was still using the deprecated version

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

Now it is working fine. =D